# Excel - Merge matching rows

Tags: vba, excel

I have an Excel sheet with a list of rows containing information in columns.
I also have a reference sheet (or copied further down in the same sheet) with lots of rows also containing strings/values in columns, in the same format.

Many of the rows in column A in the project sheet have a duplicate in the reference area.

The sheets will have different rows from time to time, but the column format will always be the same.

The macro function i need has to do the following:

Check row 2 column A for a match further down the list in the same column (there will be no triples).
If there is one, copy cells from column E,F,G,H,I,J of the row further down the list into row 2.

If no duplicate is found, or when information is copied and pasted, repeat process for row 3, etc until no more filled rows.

Like this:
[image]

That's it. Sounds simple, but i have not been able to figure out how to write the function.

Extensive googling has not given me an example of something similar.
Forgive me if I missed something, but I have tried to find similar questions and failed.

I feel like it shouldn't be very hard to solve this, so hopefully someone can help out :)

---

**Edit:**

So I managed to solve it like this:

I put the reference sheet I in a separate workbook (named it TagReference.xlsb).

In the project workbook cell O1 i added the function
=VLOOKUP(A1; [TagReference.xlsb]Sheet1!$A:$E;5;false)
and did an autofill down to row 1500 which is plenty.

That gave me the values for column E. I copied and pasted that as values into the column.

Then i did the same thing for column F with
=VLOOKUP(A1; [TagReference.xlsb]Sheet1!$A:$F;6;false
and so on until all columns were filled.

Recorded everything as a macro, and now it works fine :)

I am a complete noob at Excel, so I mostly needed a point to start at, and =VLOOKUP did the job.

Thanks everyone!

Comment: Please add the code you have tried so far, and tell where exactly you got stuck. If there is no necessity for VBA then you could have a look at the [VLOOKUP Function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/vlookup-function-0bbc8083-26fe-4963-8ab8-93a18ad188a1).

Comment: Add a column at the and with ordinal numbers from 1 to n. Sort descending, remove duplicates by column A, sort ascending, remove added column.

Comment: @brainac how would that combine the data of 2 rows?

Comment: @Peh according to description, Heffa wants to copy cells, so there is no actual merging, but rather moving data from one row to another. But you're right, they may want to keep both rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I managed to solve it like this:

I put the reference sheet I in a separate workbook (named it TagReference.xlsb).

In the project workbook cell O1 i added the function
=VLOOKUP(A1; [TagReference.xlsb]Sheet1!$A:$E;5;false)
and did an autofill down to row 1500 which is plenty.

That gave me the values for column E. I copied and pasted that as values into the column.

Then i did the same thing for column F with
=VLOOKUP(A1; [TagReference.xlsb]Sheet1!$A:$F;6;false
and so on until all columns were filled.

Recorded everything as a macro, and now it works fine :)

I am a complete noob at Excel, so I mostly needed a point to start at, and =VLOOKUP did the job.

Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 1):

s = s & "FROM [**DATA**$] AS a, [**Reference**$] AS b "

DATA  is sheet's name (Sheet with a list of rows containing information in columns).

Reference is sheet's name (reference sheet )

```
Sub test()
    Dim s As String, Ws As Worksheet

    s = "SELECT a.name, a.device, a.address, a.datatype, b.rawmin, b.rawmax, b.engmin, b.engmax, b.unit, b.format, a.description, a.alarmoptions, a.trendoptions "
    s = s & "FROM [DATA$] AS a, [Reference$] AS b "
    s = s & "WHERE a.name = b.name "

    Set Ws = Sheets.Add

    ExeSQL Ws, s

End Sub

Sub ExeSQL(Ws As Worksheet, strSQL As String)

    Dim Rs As Object
    Dim strConn As String
    Dim i As Integer

    strConn = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" & _
        "Data Source=" & ThisWorkbook.FullName & ";" & _
            "Extended Properties=Excel 12.0;"


    Set Rs = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
    Rs.Open strSQL, strConn

    If Not Rs.EOF Then
         With Ws
            .Range("a1").CurrentRegion.Clear
            For i = 0 To Rs.Fields.Count - 1
               .Cells(1, i + 1).Value = Rs.Fields(i).Name
            Next
            .Range("a" & 2).CopyFromRecordset Rs
        End With
    End If
    Rs.Close
    Set Rs = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: I thank you for taking the time to write this out. Unfortunately I couldn't get this to work. Excel/VB wouldn't recognize the sheet names as objects, or something like that (tried naming them different things and/or change names in the code. It's probably something I missed though. At least I got a different solution working eventually.